# spring.batch.initialize-schema=always does not truncate tables with PostgreSQL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have:

```
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

in my `application.properties`, I start my jobs with Spring's `@Scheduled` and I expect my application to drop and regenerate Spring Batch tables on every startup, with PostgreSQL.

However, this is not the case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: trying `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always`,  this is the property from the documentation. [Common Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.integration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema initialisation happens only once when the Spring Boot application is started and the Spring application context is loaded. It does not happen every time a scheduled method is run.